# How to create credit note in openerp in 6.1

Tags: odoo

Could anyone let me know how i can create credit note with invoice in openerp v 6.1. I have tried creating credit note from Supplier--> Supplier refund, but when i select payment--> payment order and selct invoice to pay, the credit note amount is not deducted from invoice. Can you please let me know how credit note is handled in openerp v6.1.

Answer (score -1):

i have met the similar problem.at last i found a way to solve it.i donot use te payment/payment order instead i use the supplier payment under the menu account.i creat a new payment with a minus the paid amount which make the journal entry with opposite way.  for example when we pay our supplier $1000,the journal entry is :debit payable$1000 and credit cash or deposite $1000.while when i input $-1000,the journal entry is :debit cash or deposite $1000 and credit payable$1000.
after that i use the manual reconcile function to the payable $1000 both from the credit note(SCNJ journal) and bank journal and then the staturs of credit note turn to paid.
with this way i got a payback of $1000 from supplier with balanced journal entries.
i hope it is useful for you.